# Structures on topological manifolds as colimits?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm looking for a way to define structures such as a topological manifold, a differentiable manifold, a fiber bundle, a topological foliation etc. in a unified way so that I could define a few of my own and play around with them, but without having to use full extent of the theory of sheaves that's quite intimidating to me.

I'm motivated by Hatcher's description of vector bundles using gluing maps (that are clearly functorial in some way).

I'm thinking along the lines of picking a "structure category" $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathbf{CGWH}$ such that the embedding functor $E: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbf{CGWH}$ creates colimits, then defining the actual spaces as $\mathrm{colim}(E \circ F)$ with $F: \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{M}$ for suitable "site-like" index categories. I'm trying to prove some basic propositions myself for my own education, but so far I don't understand how to define suitable structure-preserving maps between such spaces.

Is there a treatment that develops this approach that I could read? Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I had never seen it done for topological manifolds. For smooth manifolds, this is the viewpoint adopted by do Carmo in his Riemannian Geometry book and Lang in "Differential Manifolds", although they do not use the categorical language. One major drawback is that you are likely to loose the Hausdorff property with such definition.

Comment: I think this is basically what sheaves do for you. Maybe if you could give a very explicit description of the kind of treatment you want but for vector bundles that would help.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks, I was just hoping that there's a unified treatment of local trivializations but that wouldn't require that I fist read a Sheaf theory textbook in order to understand it. You can't always get what you want I guess :)

Comment: @AlekseiAverchenko I don't think that you need a whole course on sheaf theory for this. the point is that the yoneda embedding creates all colimits and the sheaf condition imposes the relation colimits (via pushouts) have a desired form, so the inclusion map you want is basically a yoneda embedding+sheaf condition. In fact you can take $\mathcal{M}$ to be the euclidian site. See [differential cohomology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.12250.pdf) for a highbrow perspective (chapter 3 and some of appendix A.5.6) for a homotopy-theoretic interpretation

Comment: Another place to look would be Dan Dugger's note sheaves in homotopy theory. I'd like to suggest something reasonable but it's tough to do without knowing exactly what you want :)

Comment: You may want to look at Cech cohomology. The cocycle or local trivialization conditions you want amount to functoriality from the category of opens.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think for topological manifolds it's a bit cursed because of the lack of good covers so one probably needs hypersheaves +mumbo jumbo. I don't think it's very natural  :(. I'd be interested to see this.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks for the suggestions! For context, I got a BSc in applied math, then switched to differential geometry for an MSc, but dropped out b/c untreated ADHD did a number on me. I recently rediscovered interest in algebraic topology that sidelined me back then, so I'm trying to self-study it. My old advisor recently published on the topic he wanted me to pursue (almost paracomplex manifolds): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07991.pdf. I'm interested in trying the top-down approach by looking at manifolds that have local trivializations with product gluing maps and their cohomology.